# In ASP.NET, how can I get an image from the code behind and display it in a <div> section?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Boss just gave me a webpage to work with, and I've never done webpages before. When I got it there was an image I need to replace

```
<div>
    <!--<img style="padding-top:5px;" class="featured" src="path/name.jpg" />-->
    html text
```

I had to go in to the .cs file of the .aspx file and a path to the image

```
Image image = new Image();
image.ImageUrl = path;
```

and then back where the old image was

```
<div>
    <asp:Image style="padding-top:5px;" class="featured" runat="server" ID="image" />
    html text
```

But I'm not sure how to get the new image to display correctly where the old one was, since I've never worked with asp files before. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: I think that the only issue is that you need to use the `CssClass="..."` attribute rather than `class="..."` when using an ASP.NET image control.

Comment: Do you mean the image doesn't display at all? or the styling isn't correct? Why not access the image control directly by it's Id `image.ImageUrl = path;` or you can provide the image path directly in your `aspx` page `ImageUrl="../Path/SomeImage.png"`

Comment: as it is now its not displaying at all.  Like I said I've not worked with asp before so I don't know how to access the image control directly by its ID I will look in to that however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the asp code, be certain to give the image element an ID:

```
<asp:image id="setincode" width="250" runat="server" />
```

In the code-behind, retrieve the control by the ID, then you can set the url:

```
Image img = (Image)FindControl("setincode");
img.ImageUrl = "Images/Butterfly.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment you can access the control directy by using it's Id in the C# code or you can provide the `ImageUrl` in your `aspx` page.

Providing the `ImageUrl` in your `aspx`

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="image" ImageUrl="../Path/SomeImage.png" />
```

Or if you want to use C#

```
image.ImageUrl = "../Path/SomeImage.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar but slightly different:

Mark-up

```
<img id="Image1" alt="image" runat="server" />
```

In code behind (VB or C#):

```
Image1.src = "Images/Butterfly.jpg"
```